# Corrupted RTF file

Tags: windows, file-recovery, rtf

My PC locked up while I was editing an .rtf file which got corrupted - when I try to open the file in Wordpad now it starts with HTML code: (removed leading html bracket)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html401strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

    <title> Personalize Your Web Browser</title>?
```

where the previous document text got converted into this format:

```
{\pntext\f11\'B7\tab}This is some original text

\cf0\b{\pntext\f11\'B7\tab}Handling \cf1 SSL Traffic
```

I've tried some tips provided similar cases here with no success - what is the correct process to revert this back to a readable text format? Is there any special editor or tool/method? Any help is appreciated.

I posted this as "corrupted" because some of the data was lost but I guess what I need is to convert the format tags back to a standard RTF document.

Comment: That looks to me more like the file was overwritten than anything else. Is there a reason why you use the term "corrupted"? Please [edit] your question to give the answer.

Comment: You will have to restore the file from a backup, your current copy, is corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

This may not help the original poster, but for others brought to this page by searching for the `file-recovery` and `rtf` tags, the standard answer seems to be Microsoft Word’s [Text recovery converter](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/text-recovery-converter/587fb316-46ed-45d0-97ba-d7adf389279f), which didn’t help with my wife’s corrupted syllabus.  I tried diffing the corrupted version with the last good backup, which was somewhat discouraging, until I tried [BeyondCompare](https://www.scootersoftware.com); which, unbeknownst to me, automatically shows the *content* of an RTF file.  This allowed me to save the text, though not the formatting.